# Spring MVC 3: Add Form for ManyToMany Relationship throws Neither BindingResult Exception

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have an Account Entity with a @ManyToMany relationship to Role Entity.
(This way I am able to have an Account with multiple Roles).

In my Account.java (Entity) i have defined the relationship as followed:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "Account_Role", joinColumns = { 
@JoinColumn(name = "Account_id") }, 
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Role_id") })
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>(0);
```

In my AccountController I have the following Actions for GET and POST:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(Account item, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) 
{       
  accountService.save(item);
  return "redirect:/account/list";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String addForm(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("item", new Account());
  model.addAttribute("roleList", roleService.list());

return "account/add";
}
```

My add.jsp form view looks like this:

```
<form method="post">
<table>
    .....

    <tr>
        <td style="width:75px">
            <label for="roles"><spring:message code="labels.account.form.roles" text="Roles" /></label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:select path="roles" multiple="true" items="${roleList}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input id="submitbutton" type="submit" value="<spring:message code="labels.form.button.add" text="Save" />" style="width:100%;">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I try open the add Dialog to enter a new Account I alway get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/eLearning] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/template/layout.jsp'.] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'roles' available as request attribute
```

I would really appreciate it to get some help by someone. I have no problems in accessing the other fields of Attribute Entity. Its just the "roles"-Attribute which causes problems. Because if I comment it out from the add jsp form then everything works fine :S.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

Thanks for your help. I dont get the exception anymore. How can I now access the value of roles? 
If I try to acces item.getRoles() in the Controller I get an empty list. How do I have to arrange it that the roles selected through the select list are stored in the roles List on the Account Entity?

SOLUTION TO SECOND PROBLEM:

It is necessary to add a custom binder to controller:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Set.class, "roles", new CustomCollectionEditor(Set.class) {
        protected Object convertElement(Object element) {
            if (element instanceof Role) {
                return element;
            }
            if (element instanceof String) {
                return roleService.load(Long.valueOf(element.toString()));
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`roles` is a property of `Account`, so you need to bind a form to a model attribute of type `Account` to modify it's properties:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute = "item">...</form:form>
```

Also note that if model attribute name (`item` in your case) differs from its class name (`account`), you need to specify attribute name explicitly:

```
public String add(@ModelAttribute("item") Account item, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, HttpServletRequest request)   { ... }
```

Comment: thanks a lot to you 2. I dont get the exception anymore... 
how can I now get the selected values from roles in the controller? if I call 
  
   item.getRoles()

i get an empty list... So I guess the roles attribute on the Entity isnt set...

Comment: @axtavt - I guess it's `<form:form` ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `<form:select` you need a `<form:form modelAttribute="account">`